# How to add multiple column in pivot table in SQL Server in my scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot

I can do pivot table with single column, But I want to do it with multiple column. How to achieve it.

Here is my code with single column

```
SELECT  ID as ItemID, 
    isnull([1201],0) as [1201], 
    isnull([1001],0) as [1001], 
    isnull([1302],0) as [1302], 
    isnull([1400],0) as [1400], 
    isnull([2001],0) as [2001], 
    isnull([1500],0) as [1500], 
    isnull([2400],0) as [2400], 
    isnull([2200],0) as [2200], 
    isnull([1201],0) + isnull([1001],0) + isnull([1302],0) + isnull([1400],0) + isnull([2001],0) + isnull
        ([2400],0) + isnull([2200],0) + isnull([1500],0) as TotalQtyCost


FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        irq.ID, 
        irq.ItemLookupcode,
        irq.StoreID, 
        --ItemDynamic.SnapShotCost,
        (ItemDynamic.SnapShotCost * irq.TotalQtyParent) Cost
    FROM 
        ItemRelationQty irq
    LEFT JOIN ItemDynamic with(Nolock) on ItemDynamic.ItemID = irq.ID and ItemDynamic.StoreID = irq.StoreID
    inner join item with(nolock) on item.id = irq.id and item.SubDescription2 = 'lux'

) L 
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Cost)
    FOR StoreID IN ( [1001], [1201], [1302], [1400], [2001], [2400], [2200], [1500])
) 
AS PVT 

ORDER BY ID
```

> As you can see in comment line `ItemDynamic.SnapShotCost` that field what I want to add another column.

How to achieve using pivot?

Comment: Show how your result should be displayed..

Comment: @Prdp one min, I will update

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7db49578-a1ef-4e53-864b-c61c5e1150f7/how-do-i-aggregate-on-more-than-one-column-within-a-pivot?forum=transactsql

Comment: Looks like you might need a [double PIVOT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenobonn/2009/03/22/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server/).